# Doing a For on a function converting to a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to get alot of informations at once, and i tried this:

```
function pegaInfo(m:MovieClip, i:int){}
```

and e tried this:

```
var i:int
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    pegaInfo(["l"+i], i);

}
```

is there anything that i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for this:

```
var i:int
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    // Assumes the loop is in the same scope as the display
    // list which contains the clips you're trying to access
    pegaInfo(this["l"+i], i);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt realize that it converts to a MovieClip Object